# Qt sidebar comes up too wide

Tags: qt

I use Qt designer (as opposed to building controls via the program) to lay out my sidebar and floating dialogs.  When first launching the application, the sidebar is WAY too wide and bears no resemblance to how I saved it.  The user can shrink it to a reasonable width, and that is 'remembered' after closing and re-opening the application.  But it doesn't create a good first impression of our application, and not all our users are savvy enough to realize that the sidebar width can be changed.

The sidebar is quite complex, with multiple forms (QStackedWidget) and each with multiple controls.  Any suggestions for forcing it to come up at the minimum width with the first use?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve the wanted behavior by setting "Horizontal Stretch" property in Qt Designer, for each of the widgets in your splitter or layout, whichever you are using to layout your components. See [QSizePolicy](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsizepolicy.html) documentation for more info.

The "Horizontal Stretch" & "Vertical Stretch" properties are located in Qt Designers Property Editor, under the sizePolicy.[See the image for exact location of properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3G5N.png)